# Are keys of rewrite conditions considered as environment variables?

Tags: php, perl, .htaccess

I wanted to know if it is the case that keys such as %{REQUEST_URI} in an htaccess file are what are being read in environment variables in languages such as Perl/PHP.

So if I set something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
```

Would that expressions value be what is stored in `$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experiment, environment variables are a subset of server variables, that can be accessed inside .htaccess. Here is the list of all the server variables: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html. Totally 45 variables.

When I printed all the environment variables in a Perl script, there were 28 variables. All of them are server variables.

Comment: ok, so it's the other way around; what I set in my Perl script can be accessed in the htaccess file?

Comment: and the value I get for said environment variables when performing conditional checks on them in my script are being read from the server?

Comment: @a7omiton No, you can't access what you set in Perl script from .htaccess. Because .htaccess is being processed before perl execution. You can set them in .htaccess and access in perl script.